# Closing a stream after sending to Response.ok()

Tags: httpresponse, fortify

I'm trying to satisfy a Fortify bug.  I have a method returning a Reader from a Clob.getCharacterStream()

```
try (final ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery()) {
    if (resultSet.next()) {
        final Clob sn = resultSet.getClob("CLOB");
        Reader reader = sn.getCharacterStream();
        return reader;
    } else {
        throw new FunctionalException(EUFunctionalErrorMessage.REPORT_NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

...ultimately it returns it to a method that calls

```
return Response.ok(reader, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE)
                .header(CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + "packData_" + productCode + "_" + batchId + "_" + timeStamp + ".xml")
                .build();
```

I need to close the reader (according to Fortify).  I cannot close it in the first method where the reader is created.  Once I send it off to Repsonse.ok, I'm not sure how to "get it back" to close.  In this scenario I can't count on the client to close.